# Dice Rolling Game - List to store dice rolling results

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, dice

I am working on dice rolling game which prints out the number of attempts (n) before both dice shows the same value.
I would like to also print out the past rolling results. However, my code only shows the last rolling results (n-1 attempts).

I have tried to google and check the past history of stackoverflow dice rolling queries and I still can't figure out how to solve the code. Please help, I think it has got to do with nested list or dictionaries, but I just can't figure it out.

Below is my code:

```
from random import randint

stop = 0
count = 0
record = []

while stop == 0:
    roll = [(dice1, dice2) for i in range(count)]
    dice1 = randint(1,6)
    dice2 = randint(1,6)
    if dice1 != dice2:
        count += 1
    else:
        stop += 1
    
record.append(roll)

if count == 0 and stop == 1:
    print("You roll same number for both dice at first try!")
else:
    print(f"You roll same number for both dice after {count+1} attempts.") 

print("The past record of dice rolling as below: ")
print(record)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your code. The first, is that I'm not entirely sure what the

```
roll = [(dice1, dice2) for i in range(count)]
```

line is doing for you.

You can make a few simple changes though.

First - your `record.append(...)` line is outside of your loop. That is why you only see the previous run. It's only recording one run.

Second, your `while` statement can be a simple `while True:` with a `break` in it when you meet your matching condition. You don't need the `stop` variable.

```
from random import randint

count = 0
record = []

while True:
    dice1 = randint(1,6)
    dice2 = randint(1,6)
    record.append([dice1,dice2])
    if dice1 != dice2:
        count += 1
    else:
        break


if count == 0:
    print("You roll same number for both dice at first try!")
else:
    print(f"You roll same number for both dice after {count+1} attempts.")

print("The past record of dice rolling as below: ")
print(record)
```

With output similar to this:

```
You roll same number for both dice after 8 attempts.
The past record of dice rolling as below: 
[[1, 6], [2, 1], [1, 6], [5, 6], [5, 3], [6, 3], [6, 5], [4, 4]]
```

Notice that I've brought the `.append(...)` into your while loop. I've also made the changes around the `stop` variable as I described.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solutions and advice on coding improvement. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something similar to @TeleNoob. Just use `while True:` and break when the condition is met.

Here's my reworking:

```
from random import randint

roll = 0
die1_record = []
die2_record = []

while True:
    die1 = randint(1,6)
    die2 = randint(1,6)
    die1_record.append(die1)
    die2_record.append(die2)
    
    roll += 1
    if die1 == die2:
        break

print(f"You rolled same number for both dice after {roll} attempt(s).") 
print("The past record of dice rolling is: ")
print(f"die1: {die1_record}")
print(f"die2: {die2_record}")
```